# Python Sine function error

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have worked for a while in matlab but want now also learn some python. but after a few days i run in some trouble...

I have similar functions. one matplotlib example and one own based on some examples (probably also the matplotlib one)

The trouble is that one function is working one not...

This one is working

```
import matplotlib.pylab
from pylab import *

t = arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = sin(2*pi*t)
plot(t, s)

xlabel('time (s)')
ylabel('voltage (mV)')
title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
grid(True)
savefig("test.png")
show()
```

This one

```
import math
import numpy
#import scipy
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

f0 = 50
f1 = 500 
t1 = 2
t = numpy.arange(0,t1,1/44100)#[numpy.newaxis]; 
#print(t.getshape())

sine = math.sin(2*math.pi*f0*t)

plt.plot(t, sine)
plt.xlabel('Angle [rad]')
plt.ylabel('sin(t)')
plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

gives the following error

> File "C:/Users/location/test_sweep.py", line 19, in 
>              sine = math.sin(2*math.pi*f0*t)
>
> TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Where is this error come from? why do i have this with te second formulation but not with the first?

A side question
When i uncomment the `print(t.getshape())`
i get also the following error.

> File "C:/Users/location/test_sweep.py", line 17, in 
>              print(t.getshape())
>
> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'getshape'

The first error looks like if it are multiple arrays. but the second says it doesn have more than arrays. Why or don't i understand the error messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `numpy` arrays, you shouldn't use `math` functions. Try use `numpy` functions:

```
sine = numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*f0*t))
```

As for the `getShape()` issue, as the error message says there is no attribute with that name. Try:

```
print(t.shape)
```

Comment: That works well does that mean when using numpy never us math functions?

Comment: the `math.sin` function works on a single angle at a time, not on an array of angles